# Revisioning is not working properly with paging module

Tags: paging, nodes

I am using [revisioning](https://www.drupal.org/project/revisioning) and [paging](https://www.drupal.org/project/paging) module.

I have set current revision for both case node view and node edit for [revisioning](https://www.drupal.org/project/revisioning) module.

I am using pagination in node pages.

There are two role A(admin) and B(below admin). If B create any node , node go to moderation mode(also unpublished) and after published (by A) when again B edit that node, node goes to moderation mode(also unpublished).

And when we see in node view page it shows the latest revision content not current but in edit page it showing current revision.

After some searching i have found that node table is showing correct data but `field_data_body` table is showing latest revision id and that is the problem .

Can anyone help why it is happening so ?